# Android image file naming Why not use uppercase

Tags: android, image, uppercase

The boss asked me  Why is the picture naming prohibit uppercase format. He believes that art staff will cause trouble. I ask whether you can tell me the reason to limit capital?

Comment: Enough of the drama in the workplace you can rename the files when you receive them from the Art staff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resource compiler converts directory names to lowercase before processing to avoid problems on **case-insensitive** file systems.

Hope this helps.. :)